# Typescript type cast Observable from variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 12.

To reduce the code of the same service logic, again and again, I'm trying to create a base class with all HTTP methods and extend the child class to use in the components.

**crud.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class CrudService {
  protected endpoint: string;
  protected listObservableType: any;

  constructor(
    private http: AppHttpClient
  ) {
  }

  list(query: {[key: string]: any}): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.endpoint}`;

    let param = ''
    for (let key in query) {
      param += `${key}=${query[key]}&`
    }

    return this.http.Get(`${url}?${param}`);
  }
}
```

To use the base class, a child class can be written as

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class CategoryService extends CrudService {
  endpoint = 'category/';
}
```

Setting `endpoint` in the child class will override the parent class and all repeated CRUD operations will be automatically provided.

This is working fine as of now, but the return type of `list()` method is `Observable<any>`.

I want to set the return type dynamically using the `listObservableType` variable in which an interface can be assigned like

```
export class CategoryService {
  listObservableType = Array<CategoryItem>;
}
```

Then the return type can be written as

```
list(): Observable<this.listObservableType> {
  ...
}
```

I'm not sure how it should be, but the above logic is not working.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-observable?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fcrud.service.ts

> Edit 2: Interfaces

Each child service has the following interface

**Paginated list page**

```
export interface CategoryListResponse {
  count: number;
  next: string;
  previous: string;
  results: Array<CategoryItem>;
}

export interface CategoryItem {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}
```

The `list()` method will return observable of `CategoryListResponse` while the `get()`, `create()` endpoints will return observable of `CategoryItem`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create generic response interfaces like this:

```
export interface CategoryItem {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

export interface CategoryListResponse<T extends CategoryItem> {
  count: number;
  next: string;
  previous: string;
  results: Array<T>;
}
```

And then the service can look like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class CrudService<T extends CategoryItem> {
  protected endpoint: string;

  constructor(
    private http: AppHttpClient
  ) {
  }

  list(query: {[key: string]: any}): Observable<CategoryListResponse<T>> {

  }

  get(): Observable<T> {
    
  }
}
```

And extend the service like this:

```
interface SomeItem extends CategoryItem {

}

class SomeItemService extends CrudService<SomeItem> {
  endpoint: 'SomeEndpoint';
}
```

You should also probably make the CrudService and endpoint property abstract.

Comment: Using `T extends CategoryItem` in `CrudService`, the `CategoryItem` is specific to Category service, but there may be other child services in different modules with the same schema pattern. Also `CategoryListResponse` in `list()` of CrudService will limit only to the Category module.

Comment: So just rename them to `whatever` and remove the properties

Answer (score 0):

Use parametrized generics:

```
export class CrudService<T> {
  list(): Observable<T[]> {
    ...
  }
  getById(id: string): Observable<T>{...}
}

export class CategoryService extends CrudService<CategoryItem>
```

Comment: But the return type for `list()` and `get()` endpoints are different. I have just put it for `list()` in the question to make the question short.

Comment: Different how? And why?

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković Please check **Edit 2**. I have added the interface and their use case.